# Use value of the filter field in ag-grid in Angular 2

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I'm making a project with ag grid. But I want to get the input text from the user in the filter field. I need the input from the filter from the user to make an http call. I searched on the website but couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Angular 2 components for this, take a look at the [PartialMatchFilterComponent](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular-example/blob/master/systemjs_aot/docs/angular-examples/app/filter-component-example/partial-match-filter.component.ts) in the examples project.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'filter-cell',
    template: `
        Filter: <input style="height: 10px" #input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [ngModel]="text">
    `
})
class PartialMatchFilterComponent implements AgFilterComponent {
... rest of the class
```

The in the onChange method you could fire off your requests as the user typed (you'd probably want to add some sort of debounce here):

```
onChange(newValue):void {
    if (this.text !== newValue) {
        this.text = newValue;
        ... fire off your http request here ...
        this.params.filterChangedCallback();
    }
}
```